# Multilateration of Sound in 3D Space

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, recreational-mathematics, applications

TL:DR - How can you find the 3D coordinates of a emitter than transmits an impulse signal?

---

**STORY:**

I'm working on something to improve my bird-watching.  I've got a camera that can take pictures of the birds when I'm not around, but currently it has to be zoomed out all the way to guarantee they're in frame.  This doesn't make for good pictures, so here's what I've done:

Mounted camera on a motor so it can rotate, zoomed in enough that the pictures will be better quality, and attempted multilateration to make the camera turn.

---

**ATTEMPTED SOLUTION:**

My multilateration is simple.  4 microphones listen for sound.  When an impulse (such as a chirp) is created from an emitter (bird), the microphones can detect the impulse, and my microcontroller can calculate the time differences between all 4 mics receiving the impulse.

My microcontroller then uses a home brew program that converts these time differences and the known locations of the microphones relative to each other into matrix form.

Once the program has the matrices, it can solve for the distance from each microphone to the bird's origin, which then can be used to figure out the coordinates of the bird relative to the microphones.

---

**PROBLEM:**

The problem with this, is that it needs to be really precise.  I'm talking ~10 nanoseconds of difference in reception time between mics in theoretical math space will cause the program to miscalculate where the bird is.

I've muddled with the code to see if implementing more mics will lessen the need for precision, but I can't find a way to achieve a tolerance greater than ~±25ns.

With my setup, I can only calculate a reception time difference on the level of 10<sup>-5</sup> seconds, so it's not possible for me to guarantee the level of precision that this type of math needs.

Can anyone think of a way for me to improve my setup so that it works?  Are there other ways to accomplish multilateration?  How else could I find where the bird is when it's chirping?

Also, I think my question is different from [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356741/cant-figure-out-multilateration-with-xyz-positions-of-each-post-and-difference).

Thanks guys, you're always awesome!!!

---

**EDIT:**

I have written out the mathematical process I have used for this problem.  Pictures of that, an excel sheet for generating initial conditions, and Matlab code for handling the maths can be found [here](https://github.com/ZugzwangKG/MultilatX).

Comment: This doesn't sound like a question for Mathematics. Could it be an issue with the devices, e.g., the quality of the microphones? In other words, better mics may be able to reduce the reception time. Otherwise, that you speak of *theoretical math space* suggests that you are simulating the problem based on observed empirical data. Have you tried a sensitivity analysis to determine which factors or features in your code are most important in driving *reception time*? That might help in bounding the problem.

Comment: @DJohnson The reason I put it in the Maths section is that I was hoping someone would know of a way to compensate for reduced precision in linear algebra, or if there is another mathematical method for locating an unknown origin.

_Theoretical math space_ means I defined a location for an emitter (so that I could generate test values for input reception times), then performed paper and pencil calculations of the matrix operations to find the set "unknown" values, and see if the operations gave the correct result, so that I could verify it would work with truly unknown values.

Comment: @DJohnson Additionally, nothing drives _reception time_ (τ).  It is just the distance between the emitter and receiver, divided by the velocity of the signal.  This is then compared between mics as time difference (Δt).

Comment: *Precision* is just another word for *error*. Issues wrt error are best dealt with from a statistical, not mathematical, point of view. Is it correct to assume that *velocity* is a fixed or constant value? In other words might that not be the very thing you want to manipulate?

Comment: @DJohnson Velocity is going to be constant.  It is the speed of sound at a given temperature (for the sake of argument, 343 m/s).  I have never previously been able to manipulate the velocity of a bird's chirping, therefore, I believe I am still unsure of what you are trying to tell me.  I suppose if I go outside and start a forest fire, I could change the temperature of the air, which manipulates the velocity of sound, but that wouldn't be very photogenic.

Comment: Defining your use of the term *velocity* is useful and limiting wrt my efforts at decomposing your challenges. Speaking more generally however, are all of the inputs to this problem fixed and nonmanipulable? If that is the case then I think that answers your question, no?

Comment: @DJohnson I'm not sure if you quite correctly understand what the problem and scenario are.  A bird chirps, my 4 microphones notice that a bird chirped (but do so at slightly different time intervals), how can I tell where the bird is?  I'm not certain what information you need to understand what I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Of course I don't 'correctly' understand your problem. Not only that I have little or no interest in 'solving' it for you. I am merely trying to decompose *your* understanding of the scenario into its component parts in order to identify things potentially left out as well as distinguish between factors that cannot be changed vs factors that can. Based on your comments it sounds like the only variables that are manipulable are the number of mics and the speed of camera rotation or zoom. If that is true then proliferate cheap mics throughout the birding area and buy the fastest camera available

Comment: @DJohnson Mate, it's not a matter of camera capabilities.  I can already move the camera, that part is fine.  The problem is that I need to generate a coordinate set to feed the camera.  The part that isn't working is mathematically determining the origin of the emitter (where the bird is).  The only thing I need, is to find where the bird is.  I don't want wires running all over my yard, and the treeline is a little far away, so triangulation is out of the question.  The mics are on a single pole by my house.

Answer (score -1):

A mayor factor you didn't mention is the distance between your microphones!
Also you didn't mention how precise you want to locate the bird.
But you can only relax timing needs if you have greater distance between the mics.

> > ...it can solve for the distance from each microphone to the bird's origin..
> >     I don't understand your calculations. What you should get is a horizontal and a vertical angle of the chirp's origin, relativ to the base line. That needs no matrix calculation - its only geometric, isn't it?

As far as my practical experience in electronics precision measurement goes, I even don't trust your 10µs resolution. There are many error sources, from microphone differences (frequency response) to reflections in trees, air turbulences, other sounds and overall white noise level...
10ns resolution from <20kHz sound is practically absolutely impossible.
But:
10µs deviation for a 1 meter base line amounts to an angle variance of 
0,2 degree.
Is that not sufficient???

Comment: I added a link to more information in my post.  In the images of the handwritten maths, there is a sketch of my mic array, where 1=1m.  I know that 10ns resolution is impossible, that's why I'm having a problem.  The maths involved necessitate a 10ns resolution.  I cannot achieve a 10ns resolution.  I'm looking for a way that I could locate the bird with perhaps a 10µs resolution.  As far as making sure the sound pinpointed is a bird is concerned, that should be fine, because I'm experimenting with FIR filters for birdsong.  As long as my (X,Y,Z) is within 3m of the bird, I'll be happy.